# Ansible expect with ktutil

Tags: ansible, kerberos

I'd like to make a kerberos keytab with ansible + expect, but the keytab file doesn't get created. What is wrong with my play ? How could I troubleshoot?

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "kuser"
      prompt: "enter your user"
    - name: "kpw"
      prompt: "enter your pw"
  tasks:
  - name: Generate Kerberos ticket
    expect:
      command: ktutil
      responses:
        ktutil: "addent -password -p {{ kuser }}@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL -k 1 -e rc4-hmac"
        Password: "{{ kpw }}"
        ktutil: "wkt /username.keytab"
        ktutil: "quit"
```

The output with -vvv

```
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available

 [WARNING]: While constructing a mapping from /repo/Playbooks/test.yml, line 15, column 9, found a duplicate dict key (ktutil).  Using last
defined value only.

1 plays in /repo/Playbooks/test.yml
enter your user: 
enter your pw: 

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [Generate Kerberos ticket] ************************************************
task path: /repo/Playbooks/test.yml:11
ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
127.0.0.1 EXEC ( umask 22 && mkdir -p "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1496244261.67-88427652465239 )" && echo "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1496244261.67-88427652465239 )" )
127.0.0.1 PUT /tmp/tmpwLW3r2 TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1496244261.67-88427652465239/expect
127.0.0.1 EXEC LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1496244261.67-88427652465239/expect; rm -rf "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1496244261.67-88427652465239/" > /dev/null 2>&1
changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "ktutil", "delta": "0:00:00.282785", "end": "2017-05-31 15:24:22.038164", "invocation": {"module_args": {"chdir": null, "command": "ktutil", "creates": null, "echo": false, "removes": null, "responses": {"Password": "mypw", "ktutil": "quit"}, "timeout": 30}, "module_name": "expect"}, "rc": 0, "start": "2017-05-31 15:24:21.755379", "stdout": "ktutil:  ", "stdout_lines": ["ktutil:  "]}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I don't have the keytab created following the above

Comment: Give us the output of `ansible-playbook -vvv` with that play

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you're repeating the same key for some of the responses. From the ansible expect module documentation:

"*If the response is a list, successive matches return successive responses*"

Replacing the kutil prompts with a list of responses should prevent the error (and deploy the keytab), eg:

```
  responses:
    ktutil:
      - "addent -password -p {{ kuser }}@MYDOMAIN.LOCAL -k 1 -e rc4-hmac"
      - "wkt /username.keytab"
      - "quit"
    Password: "{{ kpw }}"
```

More information: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html

Answer (score 1):

What actually worked for me was -

```
- name: addent of keytab
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
     realm: "MYREALM.COM"
     sec: "aes256-cts"
     passw: "ansible"
     usname: "friend"
  tasks:
    - name: keytab command
      expect:
        **command: ktutil
        responses:
           ktutil:
              - "addent -password -p {{ usname }}@{{ realm }} -k 1 -e {{ sec }}"
              - " wkt /etc/ansible/loopkey.keytab"
              - "quit"
           Password(.*): "{{ passw }}"**
```